# Audio read function

Tags: matlab

Does audioread(); function work with matlab R2009a? Every time I try to execute it, it produces this message!

**??? Undefined function or method 'audioread' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Error in ==> mnm at 4

[d,sr] = audioread('road.wav');**

My code:

**[arr,fs]=audioread('road.wav');**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

audioread() got introduced in R2012b. Use wavread() instead